# sql duplicates within duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having a hard time wording my issue. But finding duplicates within duplicates is about as close as i can get without an example.

```
ID,stringA,stringB,dID,oID
1,hello,apple,1,1
2,bye,apple,2,1
3,world,banana,1,1
```

- ID is the id of the row.
- stringA,stringB are just arbitrary strings.
- dID,oID are FK relationship to other tables.

I am trying to create a query that will give me all the rows where `oID` is `1` and `dID` is not unique and where `stringA` OR `stringB` is not unique. When finding not unique values for `stringA` and `stringB` the rows need to have matching `dID` for that comparison. If the `dID` does not match, we don't care about those duplicates.

My expected query against the above dataset above would return nothing. Because there is no row where `dID` is not unique but also has not unique values for `stringA` or `stringB`.

```
ID,stringA,stringB,dID,oID
1,hello,apple,1,1
2,bye,apple,2,1
3,world,banana,1,1
4,hello,null,1,1
```

My expected query against this given dataset would return both row 1 and 4. Because their `oID` and `dID` match and `stringA` matches.

I have tried using nested selects using `having count(*) > 1` on the fields but it keeps returning row 1 from the first dataset.

```
select * from table1
                    where oID = 1 and
                        dID in (select dID from table1 where oID = 1 and dID > 0 group by dID having count(*) > 1) and
                        (
                            stringA in (select stringA from table1 where oID = 1 and dID > 0 group by stringA having count(*) > 1) or
                            stringB in (select stringB from table1 where oID = 1 and dID > 0 group by stringA having count(*) > 1)
                        );
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

---

Corrected the result set.

Added more clarity to condition.

---

I thought this really ugly query was working, but turns out it is not working fully.

```
select * from t where stringB in (select stringB from (select * from (select * from t where (stringB in (select stringB from t where oID = 1 and dID > 0 group by stringB having count(*) > 1) or
                            stringA in (select stringA from t where oID = 1 and dID > 0 group by stringA having count(*) > 1))
and dID in (select dID from t where oID = 1 and dID > 0 group by dID having count(*) > 1)) as foo) as bar where oID = 1 and dID > 0 group by stringB having count(*) > 1) or
                            stringA in (select stringA from (select * from (select * from t where (stringB in (select stringB from t where oID = 1 and dID > 0 group by stringB having count(*) > 1) or
                            stringA in (select stringA from t where oID = 1 and dID > 0 group by stringA having count(*) > 1))
and dID in (select dID from t where oID = 1 and dID > 0 group by dID having count(*) > 1)) as foo1) as bar1 where oID = 1 and dID > 0 group by stringA having count(*) > 1);
```

Comment: I'm lost.  Your second example does not match the text.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Doesn't match what text?

Comment: Why isn't "4" in the result set as well?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Misstyped. The result set for example 2 should contain rows 1 and 4. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for now.

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE(
        ((stringA in(select stringA from t WHERE dID is NOT NULL and oID = 5 group by stringA, dID having count(id) > 1)) OR
        (stringB in(select stringB from t WHERE dID IS NOT NULL and oID = 5 group by stringB, dID having count(id) > 1))) AND
        (dID in(select dID from t WHERE dID is NOT NULL and oID = 5 group by dID having count(id) > 1))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a query that will give me all the rows where oID is 1 and dID is not unique and where stringA OR stringB is not unique.

I interpret this as saying that the count of `did` > 1 and the counts of either `stringA` or `stringB` are greater than 1.

I *think* you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by oid, did) as num_did,
             count(*) over (partition by oid, stringA) as num_stringA,
             count(*) over (partition by oid, stringB) as num_stringB
      from table1 t
      where oid = 1
     ) t
where num_did > 1 and
      (num_stringA > 1 or num_stringB > 1);
```

Comment: This is still returning a row for example 1. For example 1, nothing should be returned, because there are no duplicates.

Comment: Also, `t.*` was not working inside the nested `select` so i changed it to `*` instead.

Comment: Your interpretation is close. For the comparison of the strings, the dID must match for that comparison. The string comparison only matters when the dID match.

Comment: @prolink007 . . . You should clearly explain the logic *in the question* not in comments.

Comment: I modified the question already to reflect these comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no indication you care about how many "duplicates" exist, just that there is at least 1 "duplicate" you can use EXISTS. So:

```
select * 
  from some_duplicates sd1 
 where oid = 1
   and (   sd1.StringA is not null
        or sd1.StringB is not null
       )
   and exists 
       ( select null 
           from some_duplicates sd2 
          where sd2.oid = sd1.oid
            and sd2.id != sd1.id
            and sd2.did = sd1.did
            and (   sd2.StringA is not null
                 or sd2.StringB is not null
                )
            and (   (sd2.StringA is not distinct from sd1.StringA)
                 or (sd2.StringB is not distinct from sd1.StringB) 
                )
       );
```

See [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=030b9c0f86b7a8359f6e95b124f0928b).

Comment: That seems very close to what i am looking for. However, i need `null` values to be ignored in the matching. With what you have the `null` values will be considered matches. That is why i was using `count(*) > 1`. Anyway to fix that with what you have?

Comment: Well that was not in the original question and I am not sure what is to be ignored. Please include an example containing null values you want ignored. Obviously, your item 4 is not ignored due to null as you want it returned and my query returned it.

Comment: Sorry about that. Both strings can be null.

Comment: So it is not a duplicate if stringA and stringB are both null? But what happens if there are 2 or more rows with the same dID both with null values in stringA and stringB. So rows "5,null,null,1,1" and "6,null,null,1,1" Are rows 5 and 6 duplicates.

Comment: Your rows 5 and 6 would not be duplicates. Basically just ignore the values if they are null. Only consider them for duplicates of they are not null.

Comment: I updated reply to exclude all combinations where both stringA and StringB are null.

Comment: Still catching nulls for me.

Comment: I modified your fiddle and it seems to be working, let me check my conversion. Maybe i did something wrong.

Comment: Here is the fiddle modified with more datasets, it seems to be working in the fiddle, but i can't get it working when i convert to my actual data. Looking into it further. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=94830e4cc5bd371b74c570a551410c1d

Comment: I could not get this to work for my situation, not sure why it would not work. But i did find a solution that is working for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223389/discussion-between-belayer-and-prolink007).